# What weapon does the red specter before Old Dragonslayer use (NG+)?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I've just started a NG+ game, and killed the Old Dragonslayer in Heide's Tower of Flame. Just before the boss there is a Red Specter, he carries a lance of a sort, that was extremely annoying, but very cool! It does a series of stabbing/lounge-like attacks that are very hard to dodge.

What weapon is it? And is it available in-game?

It may have been NG++, I burned a bonfire ascetic in the area on NG, but I am guessing he spawns at NG+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The invader has the Chariot lance: 
http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Chariot+Lance

And it is possible to find this weapon in-game, by turning in the Executioner's Chariot Soul to Straid.

Answer (score 3):

In this reddit post below it seems that a player did indeed find a phantom in NG+ and kill it receiving a skirt from the enemy.

Quote from the poster Poo_Tsunami:

"I found a painting guardian in Aldia's keep! Probably old news but I haven't seen this mentioned anywhere so I thought I'd take a picture of the item it dropped and the description. I didn't have time to snap a picture of the actual phantom because it was trying to kill me.

From the back
[http://imgur.com/AtAljz1](https://imgur.com/AtAljz1)

From the front
[http://imgur.com/18K6T4m](https://imgur.com/18K6T4m)

The description
[http://imgur.com/TwZ4ZGv](https://imgur.com/TwZ4ZGv)

Although the description makes no mention of guarding paintings, the armor is exactly the same and the phantom was hiding behind a painting dual wielding square blades."

http://www.reddit.com/r/DarkSouls2/comments/210n3h/ng_red_phantom_possible_spoilers/

So yes it may be possible to obtain the lance he was using.

There is a list in the link below that tells you how to acquire each regualar lance in the game. If it was another normal players lance he was using you should be able to identify it.
http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Lances#.U1l-U_ldXT8

(I'd also like to note that this is **NOT** one of the npc invaders.)
[List of NPC's](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/NPCs#.U1mAlvldXT8)

Comment: It was not an invasion. In NG+ there a number of new enemy spawns, that shows up as red specters.They look like players, but consistently spawn the same place, even after you kill them. At least some of them do.

Comment: Found another source that said that it is possible to obtain high-powered items from the phantoms so it may be possible for you to collect his lance if you keep trying!